# How can I create single executable jar in my gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, executable-jar

I am using gradle 6.2 version with jdk 8 in my application, it's builing 2 jar files under build/libs/ directory. How can I create the single executable jar in my application?

My build.gradle,

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '2.2.0'
  id 'application'
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

jib.to.image = 'gcr.io/' + project.property('gcpProjectId') + '/my-application'
jib.container.creationTime = 'USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

mainClassName = "com.foo.Myapplication"

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

**Created Jar files:**

```
ls -ltr build/libs/
total 31184
-rw-r--r-- 1  user 15986229 Jun  9 20:22 my-application-1.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1  user 15942345 Jun  9 20:22 my-application-1.0.0-all.jar
```

Why it's creating -all.jar while executing "gradle clean build" ?
What did am wrong here?
Kindly provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: can you post, what have you tried and what didn't work out

Comment: I need to run the "java -jar my-application-1.0.0.jar". I dont need the creation of "my-application-1.0.0-all.jar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to build a single jar, after modifying the build.gradle likes the following,

build.gradle,

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '2.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

jib.to.image = 'gcr.io/' + project.property('gcpProjectId') + '/my-application'
jib.container.creationTime = 'USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.foo.Myapplication'
  }  

  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction) seems to be exactly what you need. It has interop with Gradle's `application` plugin [as well](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/application-plugin).